# How can I get value from twig form?

Tags: twig, symfony

**Supposing I have a twig like this, how can I get input value from my controller?**

```
{{form_start(form)}}
{{form_row(form.row1}}
{{form_row(form.row2}}
{{form_row(form.row3}}
   <input id='someid'>
{{form_end(form}}
```

Comment: Is `someid` what you are passing in from the controller to the twig file, like this: `return $this->render('mytwig.html.twig', array('someid' => $id,));`?

Comment: no actualy its just an id to the input field, what i need is how to get data from that input using the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access as:

```
$request->request->get('someid', 'default values');
```

More info [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object).

Comment: this is working perfect for and input, but if i change input to div it doesn't .

Comment: So Hamza, you've change your code to `<div id='someid'></div>` and the above doesn't work?

Comment: yes, actually my div has a class="editor-wrapper" which makes it like an input, but i can't get the entered data after submitting

Comment: hi @Hamza you can post only input tag element of a form to the server

Comment: Okey thanks for both of you @AlvinBunk and Matteo for your time, i guess i'm going to create a hidden input field and copy innerhtml using JS

Answer (score 0):

I used the link from @Matteo 's answer, which is also correct. For your case I think it would be like this:

```
$someid = $request->query->get('someid');
```

Try that.

Comment: this should work for retrieve variable sent via GET method, the question seems about a classic form sent via (the default) POST method

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Matteo!